# Spring AOP slow the tomcat startup time

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-aop

I am using `Spring` (4.2.1) AOP with `@AspectJ` style annotations and `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>`.

I am using the `AOP` for emailing, downloading, auditing, profiling. It works fine except that the startup time of the application is continuously growing as more AOP is being added.

Here is the basic syntax and configuration i used for Spring MVC project.

In ApplicationContext.xml file `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>`

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AuditAddProduct {
    @Before("@annotation(AuditAddProductAccessAspect)")
    public void addProductAccessAspect(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
      }
}
```

If i remove the `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` from my applicationcontext file, then server start in less than 10 seconds, but with AOP, it took around 90 second to 150 seconds. And I am definitely looking purely from a way to take the load off of the startup and memory requirements, and only want to make an attempt to migrate if it is worth the effort.

Could you share me the any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: The more beans need AOP the slower it will get, every bean needs to be checked and proxied. But why are you so concerned with startup time of your application.

Comment: every changes in the java code the tomcat server taking 3 to 4 min of waiting time, same with deployment to production. How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: Don't use AOP or switch to compile time weaving instead or proxies. Or make your point cuts smarter (currently every bean and every method needs to be checked for that annotation, the more beans the longer it takes).

Comment: what would be the benefit get in compile time weaving over proxies. How to use the compile time weaving.

Comment: Speed as you don't need proxies, the aspects are woven into your classfiles during compilation.

Comment: Thank Deinum. can i deploy the compile time weaving AOP code to production environment or only used for development environment to speed up the server?

Comment: Ofcourse you can would be pretty useless if you couldn't.